# 503 error when trying to access Google Patents using python

Tags: python, urllib2, urlopen, http-status-code-503

Earlier today I was able to pull data from Google Patents using the code below

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&q=ininventor:"John-Mudd"&hl=en&tbm=pts&source=lnt&tbs=ptso:us'
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "foobar"})

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Now when I go to run it I get the following 503 error. I had only looped through this code maybe 30 times on it (i'm trying to get all the patents owned by a list of 30 people).

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-01f83e2c218f> in <module>()
----> 1 response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in urlopen(url, data, timeout)
    124     if _opener is None:
    125         _opener = build_opener()
--> 126     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    127 
    128 def install_opener(opener):

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    404         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    405             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 406             response = meth(req, response)
    407 
    408         return response

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in http_response(self, request, response)
    517         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    518             response = self.parent.error(
--> 519                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    520 
    521         return response

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in error(self, proto, *args)
    436             http_err = 0
    437         args = (dict, proto, meth_name) + args
--> 438         result = self._call_chain(*args)
    439         if result:
    440             return result

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    376             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
    377 
--> 378             result = func(*args)
    379             if result is not None:
    380                 return result

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
    623         fp.close()
    624 
--> 625         return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
    626 
    627     http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    404         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    405             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 406             response = meth(req, response)
    407 
    408         return response

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in http_response(self, request, response)
    517         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    518             response = self.parent.error(
--> 519                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    520 
    521         return response

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in error(self, proto, *args)
    442         if http_err:
    443             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 444             return self._call_chain(*args)
    445 
    446 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    376             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
    377 
--> 378             result = func(*args)
    379             if result is not None:
    380                 return result

C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.pyc in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    525 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    526     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 527         raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    528 
    529 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

Comment: This is what a 503 is: "503: Service Unavailable
The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state."

Comment: @iamnotmaynard... but I am able to visit the url in my browser...http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&q=ininventor:"John-Mudd"&hl=en&tbm=pts&source=lnt&tbs=ptso:us

Comment: @Chris, it could be a ratelimit per IP and/or user agent.  Regardless, you should handle this error (retry?).

Comment: Use the exact same User-Agent string as your browser.   e.g. *Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)*

Comment: @selbie, how do i determine that?

Comment: @BrianCain, if that's the case would I be wise to perhaps put a sleep function after I grab each page? This doesn't need to be blazingly fast, it just needs to get done.

Comment: @Chris, yeah -- go for it and report back.

Comment: @Chris - just copy the string I just gave you. Also, read my answer below.  Tools like Wireshark and Fiddler are awesome for debugging HTTP errors.

Comment: @selbie, for real program, I won't use such fake User-Agent, but I don't think User-Agent is part of this issue.

Comment: Works without any problem here.

Comment: hmmm... copying the user-agent string per @selbie got it to go... but then it threw the 503 halfway through (with a sleep of 1s in between page pulls). Further editing of the agent string doesn't do anything.

Comment: @selbie i'll have to look into those tools

Comment: @Chris - Do you have a proxy server on your network in between your computer and the internet?

Comment: @selbie I'm not certain. So far I've just been treading lightly (ie sleeping 5 seconds in between pulls, but I haven't run my full list yet. I'll post back here when I'm done to let you know if the sleep was a sufficient (if not ideal) workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot in the dark guess:

Did you look to see if there was a "Retry-After header" in the response. It's a real possibility with 503.

[From RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.37):

> 14.37 Retry-After
>
> The Retry-After response-header field can be used with a 503 (Service
>   Unavailable) response to indicate how long the service is expected to
>   be unavailable to the requesting client. This field MAY also be used
>   with any 3xx (Redirection) response to indicate the minimum time the
>   user-agent is asked wait before issuing the redirected request. The
>   value of this field can be either an HTTP-date or an integer number of
>   seconds (in decimal) after the time of the response. 
>          Retry-After  = "Retry-After" ":" ( HTTP-date | delta-seconds )
>
> Two examples of its use are 
>          Retry-After: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT
>          Retry-After: 120
>
> In the latter example, the delay is 2 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

Google's TOS bans automated queries, sadly enough. It almost certainly detected that you were "up to no good."

source: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en