# How to Open an URL and Extract information in Python

Tags: python, scrape

I have written a web-scrape to extract google scholar information. However, any convenient tools such as urllib2 pr requests failed. And it gave me 503 error code.

And I am looking for an alternative way to extract the information. Is that possible that I can let the program open the url in browse and than extract information.

For instance, it is a link:

```
'http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=lTCxlGYAAAAJ&hl=en'
```

And how to proceed to get H-index, etc?

Comment: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Comment: No, it does not work. Still "503" error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google Scholar bans clients temporarily (using 503 error codes) that do frequent queries or appear to be automated.  You've perhaps been temporarily banned after querying too often or because it thinks you're running from a script.  You may be able to use cookies to do multiple queries within a single session.  Or wait until the ban is lifted, or wait between tries or code your script to look like it's from a web browser (changing the 'userAgent' string it sends in its query).

Do a google search on "google scholar 503" for a lot of information on this topic (that's all I did).

See also this topic:  [503 error when trying to access Google Patents using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506651/503-error-when-trying-to-access-google-patents-using-python)

Comment: Well, I actually did some research on that but hardly found useful solutions.

Comment: You need to include in your original question what you've researched, found, tried, etc.  Eg, did you try the solutions in the answers and comments on the page I linked to (ie, sleep between requests, etc)?  Did they fail?  Did you read the retry-after header?  Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you got a `503 response code` because Google detected your script as a script that sends an automatic request. You can always print a response code text to see what is going on. It could be the limit of requests per X amount of time, or something else.

To avoid it, the first thing you can try is to use a proxy.

Code that grabs entire cited by table (graph included) or test in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Scholar-pythonserpapi#main.py) (bs4 folder -> `get_citedby_public_access.py`):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, os, json

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

proxies = {
  'http': os.getenv('HTTP_PROXY')
}

html = requests.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=8Cuk5vYAAAAJ&hl', headers=headers, proxies=proxies).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# Cited by and public access results
for cited_by_public_access in soup.select('.gsc_rsb'):
  citations_all = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr:nth-child(1) .gsc_rsb_sc1+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  citations_since2016 = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr:nth-child(1) .gsc_rsb_std+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  h_index_all = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr:nth-child(2) .gsc_rsb_sc1+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  h_index_2016 = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr:nth-child(2) .gsc_rsb_std+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  i10_index_all = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr~ tr+ tr .gsc_rsb_sc1+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  i10_index_2016 = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr~ tr+ tr .gsc_rsb_std+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  articles_num = cited_by_public_access.select_one('.gsc_rsb_m_a:nth-child(1) span').text.split(' ')[0]
  articles_link = cited_by_public_access.select_one('#gsc_lwp_mndt_lnk')['href']
  
  print('Citiation info:')
  print(f'{citations_all}\n{citations_since2016}\n{h_index_all}\n{h_index_2016}\n{i10_index_all}\n{i10_index_2016}\n{articles_num}\nhttps://scholar.google.com{articles_link}\n')

# Graph results
years = [graph_year.text for graph_year in soup.select('.gsc_g_t')]
citations = [graph_citation.text for graph_citation in soup.select('.gsc_g_a')]

data = []

for year, citation in zip(years,citations):
  # Basic prints
  print(f'{year} {citation}\n')

  data.append({
    'year': year,
    'citation': citation,
  })

# JSON output, if needed
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Part of the outputs:

```
Citation info:
3208
2184
21
21
28
23
2
https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=list_mandates&hl=en&user=8Cuk5vYAAAAJ

# Portion of the regular output
2007 24

2008 30

2009 46

# Portion of JSON
[
  {
    "year": "2007",
    "citation": "24"
  },
  {
    "year": "2008",
    "citation": "30"
  }
]
```

Alternatively, you can use [Google Scholar Author Cited By API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-cited-by) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

It does the same thing as the code above except you don't have to avoid blocking and maintain a parser.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google_scholar_author",
  "author_id": "m8dFEawAAAAJ",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# Cited By and public access results
citations_all = results['cited_by']['table'][0]['citations']['all']
citations_2016 = results['cited_by']['table'][0]['citations']['since_2016']
h_inedx_all = results['cited_by']['table'][1]['h_index']['all']
h_index_2016 = results['cited_by']['table'][1]['h_index']['since_2016']
i10_index_all = results['cited_by']['table'][2]['i10_index']['all']
i10_index_2016 = results['cited_by']['table'][2]['i10_index']['since_2016']

print(f'{citations_all}\n{citations_2016}\n{h_inedx_all}\n{h_index_2016}\n{i10_index_all}\n{i10_index_2016}\n')

public_access_link = results['public_access']['link']
public_access_available_articles = results['public_access']['available']

print(f'{public_access_link}\n{public_access_available_articles}\n')

# Graph results
for graph_results in results['cited_by']['graph']:
  year = graph_results['year']
  citations = graph_results['citations']

  print(f'{year} {citations}\n')
```

Part of the outputs:

```
946
563
17
12
27
18

https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=list_mandates&hl=en&user=m8dFEawAAAAJ
23

2004 6

2005 20

2006 11
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.